# "org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException" when uploading a picture from Android

Tags: android, apache, http, file-upload

I'm trying to send a picture to rails server from Android. But when I send, I get the following error.

```
09-19 23:22:11.810: W/System.err(2704): org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException                                                                                        
09-19 23:22:12.000: W/System.err(2704):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:557)
09-19 23:22:12.020: W/System.err(2704):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-19 23:22:12.020: W/System.err(2704):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:73)
09-19 23:22:12.050: W/System.err(2704):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:92)
09-19 23:22:12.050: W/System.err(2704):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:54)
09-19 23:22:12.050: W/System.err(2704):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:444)
09-19 23:22:12.050: W/System.err(2704):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-19 23:22:12.050: W/System.err(2704):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-19 23:22:12.050: W/System.err(2704):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-19 23:22:12.060: W/System.err(2704):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-19 23:22:12.070: W/System.err(2704):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-19 23:22:12.250: W/System.err(2704): Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity
09-19 23:22:12.320: W/System.err(2704):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:413)
09-19 23:22:12.360: W/System.err(2704):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
09-19 23:22:12.370: W/System.err(2704):     ... 10 more
```

What's weird is I don't get this error every time uploading a picture, just sometimes when doing the same  process. Here are my codes. I'm using "AsyncHttpClient" (http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) for http connection.

```
public class AsynchConnector{
    static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    private static final String BASE_URL = Environment.SERVER_URL;

    public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler){
        Log.w("web", "sending POST requset to " + getAbsoluteUrl(url));
        client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }
}


public static void postPicture(String serverAlbumId, String serverUserId, String filePath){
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("user_id", CameraApp.sp.getString("server_user_id", ""));
    params.put("picture[album_id]", serverAlbumId);
    params.put("picture[user_id]", serverUserId);

    try{
        params.put("picture[image]", StorageAccessor.getPictureAsFile(filePath));
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        Log.e("---", "no image file found ");
    }

    Log.i("----------", "starting to post picture");
    AsynchConnector.post(PICTURE_PATH, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            Log.i("POST_PICTURE_RESOPNSE", response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this, by any chance?  I'm having the exact same issue, and my code is very similar to yours.

Comment: I think that was due the OutputStream writer used in AsynchHttpClient. This post might help understanding what's happening.

http://old.nabble.com/Http-Multi-part-exception-when-using-InputStreamBody-td22673677.html

And I solved this by implementing onFailure(Throwable error) method in ResponseHandler that does the same thing again. (in my case, invoking postPicture method.)

Comment: Any Luck finding the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was due the OutputStreamWriter class used in AsynchHttpClient. This post might help understanding what's happening.

http://httpcomponents.10934.n7.nabble.com/Http-Multi-part-exception-when-using-InputStreamBody-td12820.html

And I solved this by implementing onFailure(Throwable error) method in ResponseHandler that does the same thing again. (in my case, invoking postPicture method.)

Comment: I tried this solution but now I am getting a never ending loop through the onFailure Method. Am I implementing your solution wrong?